# CSV to SQLite to R: too many quotes for character columns

Tags: r, dplyr, sqldf, rsqlite

I'm trying to create a workflow where I

1. Create a SQLite database using R
2. Load some (potentially large -- *larger than can fit in memory*) CSV files into the database as tables
3. Do analysis with dplyr

It seems like something below is very close to what I want, but I'm having trouble figuring out why I have extra quotes in the `Species` column.

```
library(dplyr)
write.csv(iris, "iris.csv", row.names = FALSE)
my_db <- src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3", create = T)
con <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname = "my_db.sqlite3")
dbWriteTable(con, name="iris", value="iris.csv", 
             row.names=FALSE, header=TRUE, sep = ",", eol = "\r\n", overwrite = TRUE,
             quote = "\"", comment.char = "")
iris_sqlite <- tbl(src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3"), "iris")
iris_sqlite %>%
  collect %>%
  str

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal_Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal_Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal_Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal_Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : chr  "\"setosa\"" "\"setosa\"" "\"setosa\"" "\"setosa\""
```

Comment: I don't see a way around this other than (1) writing the csv without quotes to begin with, or (2) reading the csv into R first and then passing that to dbWriteTable. As far as I can tell, the C code in RSQLite is simply not set up to ignore the quotes.

Comment: Why not just use `copy_to()`?

Comment: @hadley if I understand correctly, `copy_to()` pipes the data through R so that wouldn't work for data bigger than what I have in RAM

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question